# MySQL varchar with unique date sorting

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql table that has a build number that is formatted like this

```
client-yearmonthdayhourminute
TKSUS-201310210353
```

I want to build a query that will pull me the last 4 days. We may have a multiple runs a day so I would want the latest one for the day.

```
TKSUS-201310210353
TKSUS-201310210153
TKSUS-201310200353
TKSUS-201310190353
TKSUS-201310180353
```

I tried something like the following but if there is a multiple runs a day it breaks

```
SELECT DISTINCT build_number FROM test_case_executions WHERE build_number LIKE 'TKSUS%' AND build_number IS NOT NULL ORDER BY build_number DESC LIMIT 4;
```

Even tried something like this

```
SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTR(build_number, 7, LENGTH(build_number)-6) FROM test_case_executions WHERE build_number LIKE 'TKSUS%' ORDER BY build_number DESC LIMIT 4;
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to pull out the year-month-day part and use `GROUP BY` on that column, then select `MAX(build_number)` in that group:

```
SELECT
  SUBSTR(build_number, 7, 8) AS day,
  MAX(build_number) AS most_recent_build,
  COUNT(build_number) AS num_builds
FROM test_case_executions
  WHERE build_number LIKE 'TKSUS-%'
  GROUP BY day
  ORDER BY day DESC
  LIMIT 4;
```

Comment: Changed the 6 to an 8 it appears to be working like I would hope. Thanks

Comment: This won't return all records if there were more than 1 per day.

Comment: @jrock2004 oh yes, sorry for some reason I convinced myself it was a 2-digit year.

Comment: @Jacob That is what the OP was asking for.

Comment: This might run a little slow if there are many records in the database, because you're performing string manipulation on every single record.

Comment: You're right.  Also, the `LIMIT 4` constraint only works if there's a build every day (and today's build has already happened).  It would be better to construct an "earliest possible build" and select valid records first (*eg* `WHERE build_number >= 'TKSUS-201310180000'`).  Then do the grouping and string manipulation with that subquery.

Answer (score 0):

I think I'd consider splitting the build_number field into separate client and date fields, but this should work:

```
SELECT DISTINCT build_number FROM test_case_executions
  WHERE build_number LIKE CONCAT('TKSUS-',REPLACE(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 4 DAY,'-',''),'%')
ORDER BY build_number DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this...

```
SELECT DISTINCT build_number
FROM test_case_executions
WHERE
    build_number LIKE 'TKSUS%'
    AND build_number IS NOT NULL
    --this clause gives you only records with date-stamps in the past 4 days
    AND DATE(SUBSTRING(build_number, 7, 9)) >= DATESUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 4 DAY)
ORDER BY
    --these two order by clauses will sort by the date descending, and the time ascending
    SUBSTRING(build_number, 7, 9) DESC,
    SUBSTRING(build_number, 15, 4) ASC
;
```